# PHP: extract unknown string delimited by known strings from another string

Tags: php

Here is a better explanation.
For example I have the following:

```
$string = "startRANDOMSTRINGend";
```

"start" and "end" are known strings but "RANDOMSTRING" is unknwon.
How can I extract that "RANDOMSTRING" based on what is before and after it in PHP?

Thank you.

Comment: You could start by coding this and coming back with your code in case something doesn't work. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php might help

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write it for you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = "startRANDOMSTRINGend";
if (preg_match('/^start(.*?)end$/', $string, $match) == 1) {
    echo $match[1];
}
```

You can use regex to extract the values between two known words like above.

The result is : ***RANDOMSTRING***

Comment: This code won't work if _end_ is present more than once, `/^start(.*?)end$/`  would be better. Using a regex for this is a bit overkill though.

Comment: Thanks for your input and pointing out the bug i will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was loking for!

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
$a= "startRANDOMSTRINGend";
echo $middle = substr($a, 5, strlen($a)-8);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.